# Use pulumi to set automatic sign up emails in aws cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, pulumi

In aws console under Cognito user pools there is a Sign-up experience tab, under this tab is
"Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm" which ends up Disabled if configuring a user pool with pulumi. How can I enable it? There doesn't seem to be an option in the api (docs: https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/cognito/userpool)
and it also seems like the aws cdk enables it by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, I think you will have to configure the properties which trigger sending a verification email. You can do this using the `autoVerifiedAttributes` property on the user pool resource:

https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/cognito/userpool/#autoverifiedattributes_nodejs